# what is solution for mysql as Error Code: 1429. Unable to connect to foreign data source: Host 'ipaddr' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serve

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created two mysql server 1 as remote server 2 as my local server
I want to use mysql federated table engine for connecting my local server to remote server with federated table connection defination as 
for my local server

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
 `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `data` blob NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CONNECTION='mysql://myuserdb:myuserpwd@192.168.0.41:3306/mydb/ci_sessions';
```

but it give me error  Error Code: 1429. Unable to connect to foreign data source connection error.

Comment: Does user `myuserdb` have the appropriate permissions on the remote server?.

Answer (score 0):

This task is related to create federated table. I and after long time of search I find our mistake of permission for remote server as I have to create separate user for such task with any host access user permission or particular host access user permission with

1 create user command.
2 grant command
from mysql.